# How to check the map type?

Tags: java, google-closure-templates

I am setting the data in model as:

```
@RequestMapping("/forms/builder/")
public void renderMethod1(Model model) {            
    SoyMapData x=new SoyMapData("class","menu horizontal right");
    model.addAttribute("pageTitles", x);        
}
```

Which is mapped to below function via Spring:

```
@Override
protected void renderMergedTemplateModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String renderedResponse = null;
    renderedResponse = compiledSoyTemplates.render(templateName, model, messageBundle);
}
```

Here  I need to check if model is of type [`SoyMapData`](http://code.google.com/p/closure-templates/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/template/soy/data/SoyMapData.java), if yes then set the type of model to `SoyMapData`else map.
 How can I do this?

I have tried below approach its not working.

Comment: Can you please give more information on SoyMapData? Which class does it extend and what interfaces are implemented?

Comment: Its a GCT API ,present in closure templates

Comment: Added the `google-closure-templates` tag.

Comment: I had a look through the sourcecode of SoyMapData (thx to Psy). Neither SoyMapData nor one of it super classes does implement the interface Map. Therefore model can never be of type SoyMapData, because the operation call would not compile. Do you miss an important part?

Comment: I just want to see if compiledSoyTemplates.render(templateName, model, messageBundle); model over here is of type MAP/SOYMAPDATA,rende of OSYTOFU allows either map/soymapdata

Comment: As I wrote: model can never be of type SoyMapData, because the class SoyMapData does not provide the interface Map (at least, if the link provided above is correct). A call like renderMergedTemplate(new SoyMapData(), ...) would not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the `instanceof` operator:

```
SoyMapData soyModel;
if (model instanceof SoyMapData) {
    // It is, get a reference using that type
    soyModel = (SoyMapData)model;
}
```

...but if you need to do that, it suggests a problem with the encapsulation in the API design. Your `render` method shouldn't need to know what kind of `Map` it's receiving, that breaks encapsulation.

There are many ways to solve that. One is by deriving a new interface from `Map` that allows `render` to do its job, and then using that interface rather than `Map` in the method signature. But that's only one way.

---

**Update**: Re your updated code, if I understand you correctly, you want to call `compiledSoyTemplates.render` with either a `SoyDataModel` argument or a `Map` argument depending on whether `model` is a `SoyDataModel`. (E.g., it's an overloaded method and you want the compiler to know which one to use.) If so, then you just use the information I gave you above like this:

```
@Override
protected void renderMergedTemplateModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String renderedResponse = null;
        if (model instanceof SoyDataModel) {
            renderedResponse = compiledSoyTemplates.render(
                templateName,
                (SoyDataModel)model,
                messageBundle
            );
        }
        else {
            renderedResponse = compiledSoyTemplates.render(
                templateName,
                model,
                messageBundle
            );
        }
}
```

Comment: Please look at the above modified code,i am still facing the problem in using this approach

Comment: @user899164: If I understand you correctly, you just branch on the result of `instanceof` as I indicated. I've added an example for you.

Comment: I do agree with your approach,i have tried the same,but the problem is i am setting the data in renderMethod1 as:public void renderMethod1(Model model) { SoyMapData x=new SoyMapData("class","menu horizontal right"); model.addAttribute("pageTitles", x); } which is not working when it makes a internal call to renderMergedTempalteModel to check type of data

Comment: @user899164: I don't think your question is about checking the type of the `Map` instance. The question you actually asked has been answered by the answers here. I think your question is how pass data to the templating engine you're using, which I'm afraid I can't help you with, not having used it. Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the type of a variable/parameter in Java.  You can check the type of the object, and if it matches your criteria, create another variable of the new type as follows

```
if (model instanceof SoyMapData) {
   SoyMapData soyModel = (SoyMapData)model;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**: `SoyMapData` is placed inside `model` in `renderMethod1`. If the parameter `model` in `renderMergedTemplateModel` references the same object (then `Model` needs to implement the interface `Map`) you need to get the object at the key `pageTitles`.

If the above assumptions hold,

```
if (model.get("pageTitles") instanceof SoyMapData) {
  SoyMapData sModel = (SoyMapData)model.get("pageTitles");
}
```

should work.

`instanceof` is used to check the runtime type of an instance:

```
if (model instanceof SoyMapData) {
  SoyMapData sData = (SoyMapData)model;
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```